# Htaccess rewriterule $1 gives index.php instead of parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get the last rewriterule to get the "lang" in php. However, it returns "index.php" when i open the parameter. What's wrong with the following code?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/home/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&voorpagina=$2 [NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `[L]` flag like this :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/home/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&voorpagina=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: No, it doesn't output anything with the L added to the line

Comment: you should put the second line before the first one

Comment: When i do that, the css doesn't load anymore

Comment: You need to add the rewrite conditions to both the rewrite rules